# Download individual s3 objects and merge them into a single file

Tags: java, amazon-s3, download, nio

The objects were uploaded in a chunk wise. My goal is to download each individual chunk and merge it into a single file. Although i was able to do it in an ond fashioned way using Java.IO I want to do it now using memory mapped technique and java.nio. S3 returns object as S3ObjectInputStream which is nothing more than an InputStream. please help i'm not an expert programmer. Also i understand things better in pseudocodes. So if you have a solution, instruct me in a pseudocode style. Accuracy will mean a lot here

Comment: Is each chunk larger than 5MB (except perhaps the last one)?  If so, it *should* be possible through some clever API requests to convince S3 to combine the existing objects into a single new object, internally, with multipart put-part+copy.

Comment: "Is each chunk larger than 5MB (except perhaps the last one)?" yes

Comment: " If so, it should be possible through some clever API requests to convince S3 to combine the existing objects into a single new object, internally, with multipart put-part+copy."  I dont think there is one